# Commentary on Vishnu Sahasranamam

Tags: vishnu, vishnu-sahasranama

Vishnu Sahasranamam has commentaries by all the three major schools of philosophies - Adi Shankara (Advaita), Sri Parasara Bhattar (Visishtadvaita) and Sri Satyasanda Tirtha (Dvaita) [the Commentary of Madhvacharya with one hundred meanings for each naama is lost].

My question: **Is there any work available where a comparative study of the three commentaries have been made - and if so the details?**